# DBEngine(0)(0).Execute DELETE to complete before APPEND

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have two statements in VBA. Here is a fragment of code:

```
'delete records from tbl_PLAN_data 
 strErr = "1a"
    strSQL = "DELETE tbl_PLAN_data.*"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM tbl_PLAN_data;"
DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
DoEvents

strErr = "2a"
'append records to tbl_PLAN_data
DBEngine(0)(0).Execute "qryAppPLAN", dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
DoEvents
```

SQL string of qryAppPLAN:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_PLAN_data ( ID, Qty, QtyPln, QtyAct, ProdT, TmStamp, TID, Wks, vol, v4, v4k, DataPln, Shift, DataPlnShift, GRD, Wk, Wkd, GRDLdKf, KFig )
SELECT tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID, [Quantity]-Sum(Nz([Qtyact],0)*IIf([np]=0,1,-1)) AS Qty, tbl_OrderDetails.Quantity, Sum(Nz([Qtyact],0)*IIf([np]=0,1,-1)) AS QA, Sum(tbl_OrderDetailsSub.PT) AS SumOfPT, Now() AS TmStamp, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.TID, tbl_Tooling.WksID, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Volume, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Vol4, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Vol4K, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.DataPln, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Shift, [datapln] & "-" & [shift] AS datshift, IIf(InStr([oprdetails],"G")>0 Or InStr([oprdetails],"Hs")>0 And InStr([oprdetails],"GL")=0,1,0) AS GRD, DatePart("ww",[DataPln],0,2) AS w, DatePart("w",[DataPln],0,2) AS wd, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.TblLoadKf, Nz([Koef],1) AS Expr1
FROM ((tbl_Order INNER JOIN (tbl_OrderDetails INNER JOIN tbl_OrderDetailsSub ON tbl_OrderDetails.[OrderDetailsID] = tbl_OrderDetailsSub.[OrderDetailsID]) ON tbl_Order.[OrderID] = tbl_OrderDetails.[OrderID]) LEFT JOIN tbl_ProdAct ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.[OrderDetailsSubID] = tbl_ProdAct.ODSubID) INNER JOIN tbl_Tooling ON tbl_OrderDetailsSub.TID = tbl_Tooling.TID
WHERE (((tbl_Order.ProdTypeID)<>"S" Or (tbl_Order.ProdTypeID) Is Null) AND ((tbl_Order.CancelledDate) Is Null) AND ((tbl_Order.RefusingReason) Is Null) AND ((Right(CStr(Nz([tbl_Order]![ProcessedDate],"12:00:00")),8))="12:00:00") AND ((tbl_Order.OrderType)<>"Pasiûlymas") AND ((tbl_Order.ShippedDate) Is Null))
GROUP BY tbl_OrderDetailsSub.OrderDetailsSubID, tbl_OrderDetails.Quantity, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.TID, tbl_Tooling.WksID, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Volume, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Vol4, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Vol4K, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.DataPln, tbl_OrderDetailsSub.Shift, [datapln] & "-" & [shift], IIf(InStr([oprdetails],"G")>0 Or InStr([oprdetails],"Hs")>0 And InStr([oprdetails],"GL")=0,1,0), DatePart("ww",[DataPln],0,2), DatePart("w",[DataPln],0,2), tbl_OrderDetailsSub.TblLoadKf, Nz([Koef],1), tbl_OrderDetails.Quantity
HAVING ((([Quantity]-Sum(Nz([Qtyact],0)*IIf([np]=0,1,-1)))>0) AND ((tbl_OrderDetailsSub.DataPln)>Date()-30))
ORDER BY tbl_OrderDetailsSub.DataPln;
```

Sometimes at second execute statement I get error "Record is deleted". It seems logic when I append records after deletion. But how to force VBA to wait till delete statement completes?

Comment: What does qryAppPLAN look like?

Comment: I ave added SQL code of qryAppPLAN. It appends same table tbl_PLAN_data.

Comment: When you say "sometimes" - how often does it fail?

Comment: We have 35 users with Access FE and BE. It happens approx. every 3 days. By the meanwhile, table is local, on FE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you create a Database Object and execute on that object rather than using the `DBEngine(0)(0)`, as when you use this, you are not only performing an expensive operation of creating a new instance of the Database, you are also trying to query the table which you just modified (deleted), so you might have a small glitch.

```
Dim dbObj As DAO.Database

Set dbObj = CurrentDB()
'delete records from tbl_PLAN_data 
strErr = "1a"
strSQL = "DELETE tbl_PLAN_data.* FROM tbl_PLAN_data;"

dbObj.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

'Optional
'DoEvents

strErr = "2a"
'append records to tbl_PLAN_data
dbObj.Execute "qryAppPLAN", dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
```

By creating a Database Object, you are making sure the operations are made against the "active" object on which you also made a modification, so would return you the right information. `DoEvents` might not even be required. I have added it, if you feel it is still causing problems introduce it again and see if it makes any difference.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks PaulFrancis. I'll test it during next week and return with results!

Comment: Just one question: must I set dbObl=nothing at procedure exit?

Comment: You can, this will free up the objects memory, upon exit.

Comment: Sorry to say but it did not solve the problem. However it significantly reduces error appearance so I marked your post as answer. I'll try to make this change in all code.